# dart, how to get generic type of method parameter using reflection?

Tags: reflection, dart, dart-mirrors

I have test application:

```dart
import 'dart:mirrors';

class A {
  void eventHandlerInt(List<int> x){}
  void eventHandlerBool(List<bool> x){}
} 

void testMirrors(aFunction){
  ClosureMirror mir = reflect(aFunction);
  var param = mir.function.parameters.first;
  //How to get the Type T of List<T> of the first param?
}

void main() {
  var a = new A();
  testMirrors(a.eventHandlerInt);
  testMirrors(a.eventHandlerBool);
}
```

I would like to be able to find out what the generic type is of the first parameter of the method passed into `testMirrors`, so in the example above it would be `int` then `bool`. Is this even possible? if I inspect param the type property is null.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```dart
List<TypeMirror> types = mir.function.parameters.first.type.typeArguments;
param.forEach((e) => print(e.simpleName));
```

prints

> Symbol("int")
>   Symbol("bool")

Comment: weird, I guess maybe dart-editors inspection tool tip has a bug in it that shows null when it should show a valid value. thanks.

Comment: I saw this too. I think what the debugger shows is a local field and what you get is the return value of a getter. The getter doesn't necessarily return the value of a similarly named field. The types and values returned from reflection are a bit weird because they are some special VM types and differ from classes defined in Dart alone.